# Custom area graph in Excel (or google spreadsheet)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts, google-workspace, visualization

I am trying to visualize my loans with area graph and have some additional needs/wishes.

For example - this is my data (made up):

```
           house    car     mower   vacation
           diners   diners  visa    visa
jan.12     60       30      0       0 
feb.12     60       30      0       0 
mar.12     60       30      0       20
apr.12     60       30      10      20
maj.12     60       30      10      20
jun.12     60       0       10      20
jul.12     60       0       10      20
avg.12     60       0       10      20
sep.12     60       0       10      20
okt.12     60       0       10      0
nov.12     60       0       10      0
dec.12     60       0       10      0
```

And the corresponding graph:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbabz.png]

I have 2 additional wishes:

1. Loans from the same account should have similar color (for example I pay for house and car with diners, and for mower and vacation with visa), so the graph would look something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVua8.png]

2. I would like to have legend somewhere inside the graph, like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O3oi.png]

Is this even possible with Excel (or google spreadsheets)? Any other ideas/tools?

Comment: This should be possible with VBA, is that an option for you?

Comment: That's what I am doing right now, I managed to add SeriesName in each SeriesCollection, but looks like I need to set x and y positions also, yuck

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, you can replace the legend with data labels:

1. Right mouse button on legend -> Delete
2. Right mouse button on each series in the chart -> Add data labels
3. Right mouse button on each set of data labels -> Format data labels -> Under "Label contains" check only "Series name"

For stacked area charts, the default label location is centered horizontally, and vertically aligned with the corresponding data. You can override the default locations by dragging the labels around with the mouse, but then you'll have to manually update them whenever the data changes.